# click outside the dropdown not working properly in IOS device

Tags: jquery

I am using add/remove class in my dropdown menu to open/close and also using the js for close the same menu outside of it.
But this is not working in IOS devices specially in i-phones;

Here the js:

```
$(document).mouseup(function{
  var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR";
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
      && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
      container.hide();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have wrong syntax, replace this line **$(document).mouseup(function(){** and check and yes **$("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR";** this line too

Answer (score 0):

you have many syntax mistakes :

1-

```
  $(document).mouseup(function(){ 
       /**code**/
  });
```

2- container selector is not closed:  `var container = $("YOUR_CONTAINER_SELECTOR");`

3-To use the event you have to pass it as function parameter like this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){  /*add event*/
    /**code**/
});
```

#### code

hide if click was performed outside the required element including its children.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mouseup(function(e){
      if(!$(e.target).is('.to_hide *, .to_hide')) $(".to_hide").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="to_hide">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
```